# regex js with multiple conditions. first condition for text not surrounded with html tag(span) and second condition surrounded with curly braces

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds

i am having issue with implement regex on text. 
i need to find all matches of text surrounded by curly braces {{ text }} but not surrounded with span tag.

i tried `(?<!<span>)(\{(.*?)\})(?!<\/span>)` without success.

example:

```
<a>mr <span>{{name}}</span></a>
<div> deliver to {{address}}</div>
```

from the text above i want to extract only address text.

thanks,

Comment: thanks its working. i need to do it contenteditable input changes. is html parser will be more efficient ? can you give code example.

Comment: its not working in js. i am getting error.
core.js:5845 ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?s)<span>.*?<\/span>(*SKIP)(*F)|{{(.*?)}}/: Invalid group
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)

Comment: Perhaps use a dom parser and get the value of the `<div>`. Then use `{{(.+?)}}` and the value will be in the first capturing group https://regex101.com/r/uEzKcV/1

Answer (score 0):

you can try this regex

```
(?<!<span>)(?<!{)(\{(.*?)\})}(?!<\/span>)
```

Comment: i tried your code ant its not working.
1.  deliver to {{address}} - works only if i type enter for new line
2.   deliver to a {{address}} a - not working.
3. deliver to <span> {{address}}  - not working.

Comment: can you explain more I think you want to extract the only {{address}} ?